# Filter Select Symfony Dom Crawler

Tags: symfony, parsing, dom, web-crawler

I have html like this :

```
<select name="MySelect" id="MySelectID">
    <option value="0">One</option>
    <option value="1">Two</option>
    <option value="2">Three</option>
</select>
```

And i want to get all the option inner text `One`, `Two`, and `Three`
How to do this using Symfony Dom Crawler ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easy use the tag names for the path like `$crawler->filter('select > option')`.

```php
$crawler = new \Symfony\Component\DomCrawler\Crawler('
    <select name="MySelect" id="MySelectID">
        <option value="0">One</option>
        <option value="1">Two</option>
        <option value="2">Three</option>
    </select>
');
$result = [];
foreach ($crawler->filter('select > option') as $domElement) {
    $result[] = $domElement->textContent;
}

// $result is ['One', 'Two', 'Three']
```